# Ansible: comment out a defined python code block with blockinfile?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Trying to comment couple lines from the file on the server (websocket.py) with Ansible but by some reason my code does not add the second comment block before OPCODE_CONTINUATION.

Idea is to add three quotation marks one line before "slots" line and three quotation marks before "OPCODE_CONTINUATION" line. My current solution tries to find the lines with regular expressions but obviously something is wrong since only first comment block is added.

Ansible version 2.0.1.0 (2016/02/22 11:04:54)

Snippet of the websocket.py:

```
__slots__ = ('utf8validator', 'utf8validate_last', 'environ', 'closed',
             'stream', 'raw_write', 'raw_read', 'handler')

OPCODE_CONTINUATION = 0x00
```

Ansible playbooks script:

```
---
- name: First comment
  blockinfile:
    dest: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geventwebsocket/websocket.py
    insertbefore: '\w{9}\s\W\s\W{2}\w{13}'
    state: present
    block: |
      """

- name: Second comment
  blockinfile:
    dest: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geventwebsocket/websocket.py
    insertbefore: '\s{4}\w{19}\s\W\s\d\w\d\d'
    state: present
    block: |
      """
```

Result

```
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
"""
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
__slots__ = ('utf8validator', 'utf8validate_last', 'environ', 'closed',
             'stream', 'raw_write', 'raw_read', 'handler')

OPCODE_CONTINUATION = 0x00
```

The file: [Websocket.py](https://bitbucket.org/noppo/gevent-websocket/src/0df192940acd288e8a8f6d2dd30329a3381c90f1/geventwebsocket/websocket.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *marker* is the primary identifier for the `blockinfile` module. See `marker` option in the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/blockinfile_module.html).

The maker defaults to `# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK` which is what you see in the modified file. On the 2nd task Ansible finds those exact markers in the file and assumes the block is present.

It should work if you provide unique markers on each task like so:

```
- name: First comment
  blockinfile:
    dest: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geventwebsocket/websocket.py
    insertbefore: '\w{9}\s\W\s\W{2}\w{13}'
    state: present
    marker: "# {mark} FIRST COMMENT"
    block: '    """'

- name: Second comment
  blockinfile:
    dest: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geventwebsocket/websocket.py
    insertbefore: '\s{4}\w{19}\s\W\s\d\w\d\d'
    state: present
    marker: "# {mark} SECOND COMMENT"
    block: '    """'
```

Comment: Thanks. It works with markers but I had to add quotation marks before it worked properly -> "# {mark} SECOND COMMENT". Now the problem is how to add indentation (4 space characters before """).

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. The `#` of course starts a comment... I updated my answer with quotes.

Comment: Regarding indention, I'm quite confused. Looking at the change history of your question above, it looked like your original question had no spaces at all. Then @ydaetskcoR added spaces and to me it looked like that was not correct since initially both code blocks had same number of whitespaces, so I removed the spaces again. Can you please review the code blocks and bring them in the form they really are?

Comment: That's correct. Original question had no spaces at all but found out the indentation problem after adding the marker.

Comment: Have you tried to not use the pipe notation? `block: '    """'` (There are meant to be 4 whitespaces but SO reduces them to 1 in comments...)

Comment: Oh, thank you! That was completely new thing for me regarding to blockinfile. Thought that the pipe notation is only way to do it. Also reviewed the original code and actually it includes four space characters before __slots__ so @ydaetskcoR edit was not correct.

Comment: A pipe at the end of a line simply means that the following indented lines are treat as a multi-line scalar value. So that's just YAML and the way how to assign multiple lines to a key. Since you only have a single line you don't need it. This also explains why the whitespaces you added to the line did not have any effect, as that was treat as the multi-line indention.